# How can I change the font color of a dynamic text field using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts

How can I change the color of the font inside of a dynamic text field using Actionscript 3 in Flash? I'd like to implement this into an if-statement, kind of like this:

```
if (randomVar == 0) {
    score.color = #0xFFFFFF;
} else if (randomVar == 1) {
    score.color = #0xFAFAFA;
} else {
    score.color = #0xAAAAAA;
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if your `randomVar` is the product of `Math.random()`, it will never produce a value of `1` and very very rarely be exactly `0`.

Comment: That wasn't actually an example of my code. If was just to demonstrate the concept Id like to have.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a `TextFormat`.   Here is an example:

```
//first, get the text format that you've applied in Flash at design time:
var txtFormat:TextFormat = score.defaultTextFormat;

//then later, in your if statement:
txtFormat.color = 0xFF0000; //red

//modifying the text format object doesn't actually trigger any changes to text fields
//you have to apply it to your text field to see the changes
score.setTextFormat(txtFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to change the color of a TextField's text is to use the [TextField.textColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#textColor) property :

```
// the color here is in hexadecimal format, you don't need the "#"
score.textColor = 0xFAFAFA;
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the best way to do this is using HTMLText. Like this:

```
var color:uint = 0xffffff;

if (score > 5)
    color = 0x00ff00;
if (score > 10)
    color = 0xff0000;
if (score > 20)
    color = 0x0000ff;

myText.htmlText = "<font color='" + color + "'>" + score + "</font>";
```